# Deno - How to fetch data from distant API or URL?

Tags: deno

I'm wondering how I can get data from other servers and API with deno ? Everything in the documentation teach me about making http servers and read files from local source. But I can't find anything useful about reading something on the network.

How can read JSON data from the Stripe API ? Or if I want to read a HTML file with text inside ?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just giving you an example of the GET request for fetching repositories of Github.

You can change the URL and Request Configuration as per your need.

In the code given below, I am calling another API of Github. By using the `fetch()` method you can do that.

`fetch()` method first takes the URL as the first parameter and the next parameter is `RequestInit` which takes the request **method type**, **headers**, **body**, etc and at the end returning JSON response of that API call.

```
const githubResponse = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=android", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });
    return response.json(); // For JSON Response
    //   return response.text(); // For HTML or Text Response
}

console.log(await githubResponse());
```

I have written the above code in a `ts` file named **Testing.ts** . So, you can run the above code by the command given below:

```
deno run --allow-net Testing.ts
```

Next, I am giving you a sample **POST** request code:

```
const githubResponse = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const body: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams({
        q: "AvijitKarmakar",
    });

    const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: body
    });
    return response.json();
    //   return response.text(); // For HTML or Text Response
}

console.log(await githubResponse());
```

You can see that I have created a `body` object and passed it in the `RequestInit` through the `body` parameter and also changed the request **method type** to **POST**.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to do a HTTP Request, for that in Deno you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the same Web API the browsers use.

To read JSON response:

```js
const res = await fetch('https://api.stripe.com');
const data = await res.json();
```

If you want HTML:

```js
const res = await fetch('https://example.com');
const html = await res.text();
// Now you can use some HTML parsing lib
```

`fetch` requires the `--allow-net` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Deno strives to be as close to the existent browser API as possible.

That means, you can use [`fetch`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#fetch). Example:

```
// fetch-kitten.ts
fetch("https://placekitten.com/200/300").then(async (d) =>
  Deno.writeFile("kitten.jpg", new Uint8Array(await d.arrayBuffer()))
);
```

CLI:

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-write fetch-kitten.ts
```

[Reference](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/first_steps#making-an-http-request)